# Исключить повторяющие строки

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно избавиться от повторяющихся строк в запросе, сам запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fio_teach,id_domzad
FROM given_homeworks,teachers
```

Пробовал ставить `DISTINCT`, но все равно есть повторяющиеся строки.

поля в `given_homeworks`:

id_domzad , filename , id_teach , id_tgroups , id_spec, time , date , dz_theme

В `teachers`: id_teach, fio_teach

Мне в данном запросе выводит всех учителей и они повторяются много раз, а мне нужно чтобы каждый учитель вывелся один раз и его домашние задания

Comment: Смотря как ты использовал DISTINCT. Не помешает еще и кусочек данных из БД.

Comment: в given_homeworks: id_domzad int NOT NULL,
  filename varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  id_teach int NOT NULL,
  id_tgroups int NOT NULL,
  id_spec int NOT NULL,
  time time NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  dz_theme varchar(500) NOT NULL В teachers  id_teach int NOT NULL,
  fio_teach varchar(200) NOT NULL

Comment: DISTINCT я написал после SELECT

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание структуры таблиц, несколько записей в таблицах, результат выполнения вашего запроса (с повторами) и какой вы хотите вместо него увидеть результат (без повторов).

Comment: вроде все добавил

Comment: Что обозначает `его домашние задания`? Приведите пример вывода

Comment: Каждый учитель задает домашние задания, задание звучит следующим образом Покажите имена преподавателей, которые хоть раз задавали домашние задания. (исключить повторения).id_domzad       - уникальный идентификатор домашнего задания

Comment: покажите пример данных - несколько строк из каждой таблицы и ожидаемы Вами результат

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT id_domzad
FROM given_homeworks(должно вывестить айди домашних заданий из таблицы given) SELECT DISTINCT fio_teach
FROM teachers(должны вывестись все преподаватели, из таблицы teachers),может в лс?

Answer (score 1):

Пример:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c28a1abddd08896f9d25c602dfa7a939

> ```
> create table `given_homeworks`
> (
>    `id_domzad` int NOT NULL, 
>    `filename` varchar(500) NOT NULL, 
>    `id_teach` int NOT NULL, 
>    `id_tgroups` int NOT NULL, 
>    `id_spec` int NOT NULL, 
>    `time` time NOT NULL, 
>    `date` date NOT NULL, 
>    `dz_theme` varchar(500) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table `teachers`
> (
>    id_teach int NOT NULL,
>    fio_teach varchar(200) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `teachers` (`id_teach`, `fio_teach`) VALUES 
> (1, 'Петров Петр Петрович'),
> (2, 'Иванов Иван Иванович'),
> (3, 'Сидоров Сидор Сидорович'),
> (4, 'Алексеев Алексей Алексеевич')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `given_homeworks` (`id_domzad`,`filename`,`id_teach`,`id_tgroups`,`id_spec`,`time`,`date`,`dz_theme`) VALUES 
> (1,'Наименование файла 1',1,-1,-100,'10:12','2018-07-06', 'Тема 1'),
> (2,'Наименование файла 2',1,-1,-100,'10:12','2018-07-06', 'Тема 2'),
> (3,'Наименование файла 3',1,-1,-100,'10:12','2018-07-06', 'Тема 3'),
> (4,'Наименование файла 4',2,-1,-100,'10:12','2018-07-06', 'Тема 4'),
> (5,'Наименование файла 5',3,-1,-100,'10:12','2018-07-06', 'Тема 5'),
> (6,'Наименование файла 6',3,-1,-100,'10:12','2018-07-06', 'Тема 6')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select distinct t.`fio_teach` from `given_homeworks` as gh join `teachers` as t on gh.`id_teach` = t.`id_teach`
> ```
>
> ```
> | fio_teach                                    |
> | :------------------------------------------- |
> | Петров Петр Петрович       |
> | Иванов Иван Иванович       |
> | Сидоров Сидор Сидорович |
> ```